# Qual è il significato di "carambolare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Io e mia madre litigavamo, come sempre, come sempre per futili motivi: con tenerezza accorata, con insofferenza per i toni e le smorfie che ognuno di noi sapeva di produrre in quanto li vedeva esattamente specchiati sul volto e nella voce dell'altro. Mary assisteva, era il pubblico. Stava infatti seduta, mentre io e la vecchia istriona **carambolavamo** da un capo all'altro del salotto.

In seguito, c'è un dialogo che riproduce la discussione avvenuta tra Gassman e sua madre.

Non capisco bene cosa vuol dire "carambolare" nel brano precedente. È chiaro che si tratta di un senso figurato perché i significati che danno i dizionari fanno riferimento al gioco del biliardo o a urtarsi rimbalzando come le palle del biliardo, ma qui non ci sono urti. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa? Fa riferimento alla discussione tra Gassman e sua madre, cioè,  sono le parole quelle che in certo modo "carambolano da un capo all'altro del salotto"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È esattamente un riferimento al modo in cui litigavano, con botta e risposta, punzecchiandosi a vicenda. Viene proprio dalla *carambola* del biliardo, cioè una palla che colpisce un'altra palla che a sua volta colpisce un'altra palla. È dunque la mossa in cui devi colpire l'avversario ed è proprio questo che Gassman e sua madre facevano, si "colpivano con le parole", e quindi le parole *rimbalzavano* da un lato all'altro della stanza, come suppongo sia dimostrabile dal dialogo tra i due che segue questa descrizione.

Facendo una ricerca su Google Books ho trovato un riferimento nel libro "I revisionisti" di Thomas Mullen (nella traduzione di Gianni Pannofino visionabile, per l'appunto, su [Google Books](https://books.google.es/books?id=3gREVPbOUCcC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=carambolavano&f=false)) in cui alla pagina 60 è scritto "Queste erano storie e domande a cui non poteva dar voce. Gli *carambolavano* in testa come ecchi di parole non dette". Il senso è esattamente lo stesso, quello di rimbalzare.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Ma Thomas Mullen non scrive in italiano... Chi è il traduttore, cioè l'autore reale della frase che riporti?

Comment: @DaG Dal link di Google: "Traduzione di Gianni Pannofino".

Comment: Grazie, @A.Darwin . L'ho aggiunto alla risposta perché quel “carambolare” ci dice qualcosa sull'idioletto di Pannofino, non di Mullen.

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=3gREVPbOUCcC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2